# Flutter - How to log to a file on mobile instead of console

Tags: flutter, logging

The docs says

```
var logger = Logger(
  filter: null, // Use the default LogFilter (-> only log in debug mode)
  printer: PrettyPrinter(), // Use the PrettyPrinter to format and print log
  output: null, // Use the default LogOutput (-> send everything to console)
);
```

I'm confused on what the parameter should be to the **output** to make it log to a file

something like `file(../lib/file.txt)` ?

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/logger/latest/logger/LogOutput-class.html

Comment: @pskink can you provide an example please

Comment: check https://github.com/leisim/logger/blob/master/lib/src/outputs/console_output.dart for example

Answer (score 9):

@user2962142,

You have to create class FileOutput with extends LogOutput and pass in output param of Logger() like below

> _logger = Logger(printer: PrettyPrinter(), output: FileOutput());

Where FileOutput Class is responsible for writing pretty logs in a file as

```
class FileOutput extends LogOutput {
  FileOutput();

  File file;

  @override
  void init() {
    super.init();
    file = new File(filePath);
  }

  @override
  void output(OutputEvent event) async {
    if (file != null) {
      for (var line in event.lines) {
        await file.writeAsString("${line.toString()}\n",
            mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
      }
    } else {
      for (var line in event.lines) {
        print(line);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try f_logs plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/f_logs

This will export a .txt file

Comment: can you provide an example of it as on pub.dev is bit confusing

Comment: f_logs seems abandoned.  At the time of this writing it hasn't been touched in 10 months and has 24 unaddressed issues with [one regarding iOS permissions](https://github.com/zubairehman/Flogs/issues/32) effectively making the package useless for any Flutter app that targets iOS.

Comment: Actually it still works... So one can use it

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but you can write to the console using debugPrint() and upon execution specify a text file to output to along with the run command.

I wanted to do this from a test and used the following to output from the terminal to a text file in the root of the project:

```
flutter test --no-pub test\my_test.dart >output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Talker over `f_logs` which is not very well maintained (i.e. intl hardcoded to 17.x...) - `talker` does everything and more and integrates with flutter optionally.

It has disk persistence, export capabilities, and more. It has more downloads and stars than `f_logs`.

Find it here: https://github.com/Frezyx/talker/tree/master

On pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/talker